# writing and reading from an xml resource Android

Tags: android, xml

How to write an xml resource and that will have different variables to be used for parsing within an android app. For example I want to set values for a drawer navigation. When an item is seleccted from the menu, the color of text will change accordingly within the activity which hosts navigation drawer.

```
Categorie = 1;
title = Item 1;
color = #ffffff;

Categorie = 2;
title = Item 2;
color = #ffffff;
```

I know the logic just not sure how doing this from an XML. The reason behind this is that the xml can be downloaded in the initial setup of the app and thus all I need to do to change the entire navigation within the app is using a new xml resource, allowing me to update the app without having to manually change everything and release updates all the time.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your case correctly, I would suggest you to create a specific file in which the layout parameters are stored. By updating only this file, you could adapt e.g. button colors as follows:

```
Button mButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
mButton.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000")); // custom color
```

Hope this helps!